# Can I use IBM 5702 SCSI controller in a PC?

Tags: scsi, controller, x86-64

I found an old IBM made SCSI controller type 5702 (PN 97P3359) in the "stuff stored just in case instead of throwing it away" storage.

I happen to need connecting an Ultra320 SCSI disk and make backup of its data, I'm not going to use it in the long run and so I don't care about performance, etc. If this just happens to work to allow me to make backup, so much the better that I don't need to get out and buy something else.

The problem is IBM has some docs about this controller in context of what can be used on Power systems.

Obviously I need to plug this controller into PC. This controller does have PCI-X interface, so I figured maybe it's compatible? Obviously the question is can I plug that in and have this thing working instead of burning.

I'd rather not test this empirically, so I ask here before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a machine with a PCI-X slot? These were extremely rare outside of servers and some high end workstations of the time. Many PCI-X cards will work in an ancient PCI slot, but at the slower 32-bit bandwidth. I don't know if that card is one of them. If not, it won't explode, just not do anything. If you pop it in and the OS recognizes it, you're probably OK. But you may need a much older version of Linux to have drivers for the card.